# cmake cannot find the version of boost 1.59

Tags: boost, cmake

I want to setup CGAL-4.7 and, in order to do that, i need to install boost. Specifically, i use boost-1.59. Cmake version is 3.4.0. I get the following message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1247 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 0.0.0

  Boost include path: C:/local/boost_1_59_0/boost

  Detected version of Boost is too old.  Requested version was 1.39 (or
  newer).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:6 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:649 (include)
```

**EDIT**

The main error is this:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:721
(file): file STRINGS file "C:/local/boost_1_59_0/boost/boost/version.hpp" cannot be read. Call Stack (most recent call first): cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:6
(find_package) cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85(include)
CMakeLists.txt:649 (include)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Mistake. The main error is this:

CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:721 (file):
  file STRINGS file "C:/local/boost_1_59_0/boost/boost/version.hpp" cannot be
  read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:6 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:649 (include)

Comment: I am in windows. Is not boost-devel for linux?

Comment: Does `C:/local/boost_1_59_0/boost/boost/version.hpp` exist on your system?  If that path is wrong, look for a similar one that contains `version.hpp`.

Comment: Update your question to include the relevant part of your `CMakeLists.txt`.  If your getting this error from CGAL's `CMakeLists.txt`, then include the command-line you used when you ran cmake.